# Viewing local dev sites built in Visual Studio on Virtual Box via Mac browsers

Tags: cross-browser, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have several sites set up on my Virtual Box Windows VM build.

When running the sites locally in Visual Studio is it possible for me to view the site from the Mac that has Virtual Box installed.

I need to do this for cross browser testing purposes.

Comment: What kind of networking did you configure for the VM?

Comment: It is 'Bridged' in the Virtual Box netwrok settings.

Comment: And can you access your VM from the host? What kind of error do you get if not?

Comment: How do you mean?  I don't really know how to access the VM from the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bridged networking, your VM should be accessible in your network as if it were a physical host, IIRC. The host should have an IP address and a host name. In the VM, run ipconfig in a command line. Then you should be able to ping your machine from the physical host, for example, at least using the IP address from ipconfig. And you may be able to access your sites by using a URL like `http://<vm-hostname>/path` in a browser on your physical machine. Or if that doesn't work, you should check the firewall in the VM.